# Process bunches of records in seperate threads and wait for them all to finish

Tags: c#, multithreading

I feel like there is a better way of writing this code which waits for multiple threads to finish their work (i.e. without using two loops), but my colleagues and I are drawing a blank.

```
private static void ProcessRecords(long[] recordIds)
{
    var threads = new List<Thread>();
    var recordsPerThread = recordIds.Length / Settings.Default.WorkerThreads + 1;

    for (var i = 0; i < Settings.Default.WorkerThreads; i++)
    {
        var t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Program.SetOwner));
        threads.Add(t);
        t.Start(recordIds.Skip(i * recordsPerThread).Take(recordsPerThread));
    }

    // Wait until all threads have completed
    foreach (var t in threads)
    {
        t.Join();
    }
}

private static void SetOwner(object o)
{
    var recordIds = o as IEnumerable<long>;

    using (Database d = Program.GetDatabase())
    {
        Account owner = Program.GetOwner(d);

        foreach (long id in recordIds)
        {
            try
            {
                var record = d.GetRecordById(id);
                record.Owner = owner;
                record.Save();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // code to log error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a particular reason for using threads directly, rather than the [Task Parallel Library](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming)?

Comment: Yes, I tried using PLINQ at first, but the `Program.SetOwner` method opens a third-party "database" connection (which cannot be shared across threads) and so each thread needed it's own connection, our tests showed that that was slower than using a single thread to process the records. By using the code above each thread has it's own connection and deals with a "fair share" of the records. I am open to other suggestions though.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could use PLINQ but it would require adjusting the `SetOwner` method and the _database_ connection. Could you post this one too?

Comment: So I assume you had something like `recordIds.AsParallel().ForAll(Program.SetOwner)` before?

Comment: @t3chb0t I've added the `Program.SetOwner` code to the question.

@PieterWitvoet That's correct, along a dash of `WithDegreeOfParallelism()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So your original approach looked something like this:

```
recordIds.AsParallel()
    .WithDegreeOfParallelism(...)
    .ForAll(id => SetOwner(id));
```

which involved a separate call to `SetOwner` for each record. Because `SetOwner` has a lot of overhead per call, it's indeed much better to let it operate on batches rather than individual items. But you don't need to use threads for that directly:

```
recordIds
    .SplitIntoBatches(Settings.Default.WorkerThreads)
    .AsParallel()
    .WithDegreeOfParallelism(Settings.Default.WorkerThreads)
    .ForAll(batch => SetOwner(batch));


public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SplitIntoBatches<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, int numberOfBatches)
{
    var batchSize = (items.Count() + numberOfBatches - 1) / numberOfBatches;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBatches; i++)
        yield return items.Skip(i * batchSize).Take(batchSize);
}
```

Comment: A 2D array, I like your thinking! I will give that a go and report back, many thanks.

Comment: Seems to work well, and looks nicer, thanks!

Comment: Nice idea to make it generic & yield (I've never actually written function which yields before), but can you explain `batchSize = (items.Count() + numberOfBatches - 1) / numberOfBatches` please? It doesn't seem to make sense to me.

Comment: It does the same as your +1, but only if the item count is not exactly divisible by the number of batches.

Answer (score 3):

It's so hard to parallelize this becasue `SeOwner` has a hardcoded database dependency that it shouldn't. In fact it should get it via a parameter like `GetOwner` does. But not only this, it should also recieve the owner via a parameter.

The very simple version of it should just do the job of setting the owner, nothing else, no database creations, not looping etc:

```
private static void SetOwner(object database, Account owner, long recordId)
{
    try
    {
        var record = database.GetRecordById(recordId);
        record.Owner = owner;
        record.Save();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // code to log error
    }
}
```

Having this you can now update your code processing the records and use the `Parallel.ForEach`. With `localInit` your first create a database instance per thread and with `localFinally` you dispose it. Then on each loop within the same thread `body` gets called and the `local` is passed to it along with the `recordId` and a `loopState` (that allows you to stop/break the loop if necessary). For easier debugging you can set `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` to `1`.

```
Parallel.ForEach
(
    source: recordIds,
    parallelOptions: new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount },
    localInit: () => new { Database = Program.GetDatabase() },
    body: (recordId, loopState, local) =>
    {
        SetOwner(local.Database, GetOwner(local.Database), recordId);
        return local;
    },
    localFinally: local => local.Database.Dispose()
);
```

Comment: If I understand your code correctly, then this shares a database connection across all the threads, which the third-party code does not support (it throws an Exception).

Comment: @Jocie nope, it uses one connection per thread.

Comment: Ah, we tried that and it was slower than using a single thread. Thanks for your input though!

Comment: @Jocie this is of course always possible. Most of the time it's hard to predict whether a parallel implementation will really be faster so your approach by trying different techniques was correct ;-)

Comment: It might be slower because the original code only calls `GetOwner` once per batch, while this calls it for every record. Moving that call into `localInit` should help.

Comment: You can't put `GetOwner` into local as it is dependent on `local.Database`

Comment: @Jocie maybe ;-) I don't know. I just wanted to show you a general pattern how such problems can be dealt with. I don't know your exact implementation of all the methods so you need to figre out the rest yourself.

Comment: @Jocie: `localInit` can accept any method with the right signature, not just single-expression lambda's: `() => { var db = Program.GetDatabase(); var owner = GetOwner(db); return new { Database = db, Owner = owner }; }`